# loop through all td elements in a table

Tags: jquery

How would I loop through all the td elements in a table? I need to find the id of each td and compare it against a value.  Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop all your td's:

```
$("td").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    // compare id to what you want
});
```

Comment: I would suggest combining what wong2 suggests: `#table-id > td` this would ensure that you specifically link to a known table by the id and  only get the td(s) 1 level below the table. with the above all td in the page are found (unless that is what you want :)).

Comment: However, as I've commented, you should use just a space instead of `>` as `td` elements are never direct descendants of `table` elements.

Comment: Absolutely, but he didn't specify his structure or any possible selector so.

Answer (score 6):

`var all_td_in_a_table = $("#table-id td")`,

then you can do a loop

Comment: `td` elements are not, ever, direct descendants of `table` elements; there must be `tr` elements between them in the element hierarchy. Therefore, use just a space, which is a general descendant selector, instead of the direct descendant selector, `>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#tableId').find('tr').each(function () {
 $(this).find("td[id^='tdId']").each(function (i, item) {
      //do your task here
        });
 });
```

Or the effective one is get all the tds from table first

```
var totalTdsInTable = $("#table-id td");
```

Now loop through totalTdsInTable