# Function to loop through all td elements in a table when table object is passed without using id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a function with jQuery in order to loop through each `<td>` in a table, when there are several tables in the page with no specific ids.

I understand how to [loop through all td elements in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193973/loop-through-all-td-elements-in-a-table), even when [table id is passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886570/looping-through-tr-when-table-id-is-passed), but I can't get it to work when the function, which is triggered by one of the child `<td>` elements, has to use the parent table.

I've tried something (very silly) like

```
var tbl = $(this).closest('table');
$(tbl+" <td>").each(function() {
```

But ofcourse this doens't work at all.

I can generate ids to make things easier but I'm sure there's a way to do it more elegantly only with jQuery.

Comment: [`$(tbl).find('<td>').each(function() {`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks, this works but with a slight change - $(tbl).find('td').each(function() {

Comment: yes of course ;) just copied your example, and didn't change that bit. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$("td", tbl).each(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:get the id of table and use it with `.each`.

```
var tbl = $(this).closest('table');
$(tbl).find("td").each(function() {
//do stuff here...
}
```

**EDIT:Without id....**

Comment: then solution by yoshi,alon and oh Jong Am will work like charm for you... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var tbl = $(this).closest('table');
tbl.find('td').each(function() {
   var $td = $(this);//"this" keyword is current context;"td" element, so $(this) is a "TD  element" jquery object.


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any element in the table like `this` from an event handler, then you can do this:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("td").each(function(index, element) {
    // you will get each td in the table here
});
```